# No valid kits found - Mac

Tags: qt, homebrew, qt-creator

I installed brew installed qt and qt-creator.
When trying to create a new qmake empty project I get stuck on the Kit selection page saying that no valid kits were found, and can't go any farther. I tried searching the web but I did not find my answer.
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks !

Comment: In Qt Creator preferences, check if your Qt version is detected and your compiler, also. Then, create a new kit or fix the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Well even I had the same problem, but it was because during the installation process you have to select the Qt version and then do the installation. This installs all the necessary components but increases the file size.

Comment: Yeah I know, it worked for me when I installed it from the official Qt website. When using homebrew it does not seem to find the kits :/